# How to split Blazor WASM components code of C# and HTML in different files?

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, blazor-client-side

I've some background in Web Development, mostly in ASP MVC and JavaScript with Angular.

Currently, I'm learning **Blazor WASM** and I'm somehow "confused" because I cannot find any example of how to split the below code into two files.

This is the example code of one **component** from the default template:

**Counter.razor**

```
@page "/counter"

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```

Is it any way to split like into the Angular Web Components? .html and .ts? In this case .razor and .razor.cs?

**Counter.razor** - HTML

```
@page "/counter"

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>
```

**Counter.razor.cs** - C#

```
@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```

I've developed relatively complex SPAs in Angular and sites in ASP MVC and this solution is I'd say okay when your projects are small, but I don't like to mix JS/C# code in the same HTML page. I have faced some complex situations like these ones in the past and it became hard to maintain.

Any idea how to split it? Thanks.

Comment: It is explained here clearly, completely and without mistakes :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.1#partial-class-support

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create partial classes to separate the code from the HTML:

[Edit: Thanks to Enet's information]
If you name the file [classname].razor.cs, the file becomes a single object in solution explorer. I have learned two things before lunch today; time to slow down.

If you have a Page (or component) in a Blazor project named Index.razor

Edit: .Net Core 3.1 is required for partial class support (per Federico Navarrete).

Create a C# class in the same directory with the same name.

At first it will not compile, so you have to add the word partial:

```
public partial class Index
{
    ...
}
```

I prefer to put all my code in a partial class because .razor pages do not have the drop down menu for methods and properties like a .cs file does.

[image]

Comment: "The correct syntax is just [classname].cs, not [classname].razor.cs like you tried." ... This is not true. Both syntax are fine, and if anything, the correct syntax is [classname].razor.cs...

Comment: You are correct enet. I had never tried that. In face once I did, the file then becomes a single object in solution explorer.

Comment: Great answer! Maybe you can just add that you need to have 3.1+ SDK!

Comment: What SDK are you referring to Federico? If I update that I want to make sure I understand what I am saying. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you just need to inherit from ComponentBase in your code-behind .cs file, and then inherit that class at the top of your .razor file.

c# file:

```
public class MyComponent : ComponentBase
```

razor file:

```
@inherits MyComponent
```

This article has a more thorough explanation, though it is from 2018 so might have some outdated pieces. https://gunnarpeipman.com/blazor-code-behind/